# Which of the IDS 11.70 onconfig parameters can be changed to maximize performance for a DSS app?

Tags: informix

Informix 11.70.TC5DE, 
Windows Vista with Dual Core Processor, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD:

During the installation of this server, I specified it was going to be used for a data warehousing application. These are the onconfig parameters the install script generated.
Can any of these parameters be changed to maximize the performance of the server?

```
#(onconfig.ol_informix1170) -  for data warehousing app.

ROOTNAME rootdbs
ROOTPATH C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\OL_INF~2\dbspaces\rootdbs.000
ROOTOFFSET 0
ROOTSIZE 312992
MIRROR 0
MIRRORPATH 
MIRROROFFSET 0

PHYSFILE        49152           
PLOG_OVERFLOW_PATH 
PHYSBUFF 512

LOGFILES        6               
LOGSIZE 10000
DYNAMIC_LOGS 2
LOGBUFF 256

LTXHWM 70
LTXEHWM 80

MSGPATH C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\ol_informix1170_1.log
CONSOLE C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Informix\11.70\ol_informix1170_1.con

TBLTBLFIRST 0
TBLTBLNEXT 0
TBLSPACE_STATS 1

DBSPACETEMP tempdbs
SBSPACETEMP 

SBSPACENAME sbspace
SYSSBSPACENAME 
ONDBSPACEDOWN 2

SERVERNUM 6
DBSERVERNAME ol_informix1170_1
DBSERVERALIASES dr_informix1170_1

NETTYPE olsoctcp,1,150,NET
LISTEN_TIMEOUT 60
MAX_INCOMPLETE_CONNECTIONS 1024
FASTPOLL 1
NS_CACHE host=900,service=900,user=900,group=900

MULTIPROCESSOR 0
VPCLASS cpu,num=1,noage
VP_MEMORY_CACHE_KB 0
SINGLE_CPU_VP 1

#VPCLASS aio,num=1
CLEANERS 2
AUTO_AIOVPS 1
DIRECT_IO 0

LOCKS 2000
DEF_TABLE_LOCKMODE page

RESIDENT 0
SHMBASE 0xc000000L
SHMVIRTSIZE 209920
SHMADD 6560
EXTSHMADD 8192
SHMTOTAL 0
SHMVIRT_ALLOCSEG 0,3
#SHMNOACCESS 0x70000000-0x7FFFFFFF

CKPTINTVL 300
AUTO_CKPTS 1
RTO_SERVER_RESTART 60

BLOCKTIMEOUT 3600

CONVERSION_GUARD 2
RESTORE_POINT_DIR $INFORMIXDIR\tmp

TXTIMEOUT 300
DEADLOCK_TIMEOUT 60

HETERO_COMMIT 0

TAPEDEV \\.\TAPE0
TAPEBLK 16
TAPESIZE 0

LTAPEDEV 
LTAPEBLK 16
LTAPESIZE 0

BAR_ACT_LOG $INFORMIXDIR\tmp\bar_act.log
BAR_DEBUG_LOG $INFORMIXDIR\tmp\bar_dbug.log
BAR_DEBUG 0
BAR_MAX_BACKUP 0
BAR_RETRY 1
BAR_NB_XPORT_COUNT 20
BAR_XFER_BUF_SIZE 15
RESTARTABLE_RESTORE ON
BAR_PROGRESS_FREQ 0
BAR_BSALIB_PATH 
BACKUP_FILTER 
RESTORE_FILTER 
BAR_PERFORMANCE 0
BAR_CKPTSEC_TIMEOUT 15

ISM_DATA_POOL ISMData
ISM_LOG_POOL ISMLogs

DD_HASHSIZE 31
DD_HASHMAX 10

DS_HASHSIZE 31

DS_POOLSIZE 127

PC_HASHSIZE 31
PC_POOLSIZE 127
PRELOAD_DLL_FILE 

STMT_CACHE 0
STMT_CACHE_HITS 0
STMT_CACHE_SIZE 512
STMT_CACHE_NOLIMIT 0
STMT_CACHE_NUMPOOL 1

USEOSTIME 0
STACKSIZE 64
ALLOW_NEWLINE 0

USELASTCOMMITTED NONE

FILLFACTOR 90
MAX_FILL_DATA_PAGES 0
BTSCANNER num=1,threshold=5000,rangesize=-1,alice=6,compression=default

ONLIDX_MAXMEM 188928

MAX_PDQPRIORITY 100
DS_MAX_QUERIES 1
DS_TOTAL_MEMORY 188928
DS_MAX_SCANS 1
DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM 188928
DATASKIP 

OPTCOMPIND 2
DIRECTIVES 1
EXT_DIRECTIVES 0
OPT_GOAL -1
IFX_FOLDVIEW 0
AUTO_REPREPARE 1
USTLOW_SAMPLE 0

RA_PAGES 64
RA_THRESHOLD 16
BATCHEDREAD_TABLE 1
BATCHEDREAD_INDEX 1
BATCHEDREAD_KEYONLY 0

EXPLAIN_STAT 1
#SQLTRACE level=low,ntraces=1000,size=2,mode=global

#DBCREATE_PERMISSION informix
#DB_LIBRARY_PATH 
IFX_EXTEND_ROLE 1
SECURITY_LOCALCONNECTION 
UNSECURE_ONSTAT 
ADMIN_USER_MODE_WITH_DBSA 
ADMIN_MODE_USERS 

PLCY_POOLSIZE 127
PLCY_HASHSIZE 31
USRC_POOLSIZE 127

USRC_HASHSIZE 31

STAGEBLOB 
OPCACHEMAX 0

SQL_LOGICAL_CHAR OFF

SEQ_CACHE_SIZE 10

ENCRYPT_HDR 
ENCRYPT_SMX 
ENCRYPT_CDR 0
ENCRYPT_CIPHERS 
ENCRYPT_MAC 
ENCRYPT_MACFILE 
ENCRYPT_SWITCH 

CDR_EVALTHREADS 1,2
CDR_DSLOCKWAIT 5
CDR_QUEUEMEM 4096
CDR_NIFCOMPRESS 0
CDR_SERIAL 0
CDR_DBSPACE 
CDR_QHDR_DBSPACE 
CDR_QDATA_SBSPACE 
CDR_SUPPRESS_ATSRISWARN 
CDR_DELAY_PURGE_DTC 0
CDR_LOG_LAG_ACTION ddrblock
CDR_LOG_STAGING_MAXSIZE 0
CDR_MAX_DYNAMIC_LOGS 0

DRAUTO 0
DRINTERVAL 30
DRTIMEOUT 30
HA_ALIAS 
DRLOSTFOUND $INFORMIXDIR\etc\dr.lostfound
DRIDXAUTO 0
LOG_INDEX_BUILDS 
SDS_ENABLE 
SDS_TIMEOUT 20
SDS_TEMPDBS 
SDS_PAGING 
SDS_LOGCHECK 0
UPDATABLE_SECONDARY 0
FAILOVER_CALLBACK 
FAILOVER_TX_TIMEOUT 0
TEMPTAB_NOLOG 0
DELAY_APPLY 0
STOP_APPLY 0
LOG_STAGING_DIR 
RSS_FLOW_CONTROL 0
ENABLE_SNAPSHOT_COPY 0
SMX_COMPRESS 0

ON_RECVRY_THREADS 2
OFF_RECVRY_THREADS 5

DUMPDIR $INFORMIXDIR\tmp
DUMPSHMEM 1
DUMPGCORE 0
DUMPCORE 0

DUMPCNT 1

ALARMPROGRAM $INFORMIXDIR\etc\alarmprogram.bat
ALRM_ALL_EVENTS 0
#SYSALARMPROGRAM $INFORMIXDIR\etc\evidence.bat
STORAGE_FULL_ALARM 600,3

RAS_PLOG_SPEED  10982           
RAS_LLOG_SPEED 0

EILSEQ_COMPAT_MODE 0

QSTATS 0
WSTATS 0

#VPCLASS         MQ,noyield
MQSERVER 
MQCHLLIB 

MQCHLTAB 

#VPCLASS jvp,num=1
#JVPJAVAHOME    $INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa\jre
#JVPHOME        $INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa
JVPPROPFILE $INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa\.jvpprops
JVPLOGFILE $INFORMIXDIR\jvp.log
#JDKVERSION    1.5
#JVPJAVALIB     \bin
#JVPJAVAVM      jvm
#JVPARGS        -verbose:jni
#JVPCLASSPATH  $INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa\krakatoa_g.jar;$INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa\jdbc_g.jar
JVPARGS -Dcom.ibm.tools.attach.enable=no
JVPCLASSPATH $INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa\krakatoa.jar;$INFORMIXDIR\extend\krakatoa\jdbc.jar

BUFFERPOOL  default,buffers=10000,lrus=8,lru_min_dirty=50.00,lru_max_dirty=60.50
BUFFERPOOL  size=4K,buffers=13108,lrus=16,lru_min_dirty=70.00,lru_max_dirty=80.00
AUTO_LRU_TUNING 1

USERMAPPING OFF

SP_AUTOEXPAND 1
SP_THRESHOLD 0
SP_WAITTIME 30

DEFAULTESCCHAR \

LOW_MEMORY_RESERVE 0
LOW_MEMORY_MGR 0

REMOTE_SERVER_CFG 
REMOTE_USERS_CFG 

S6_USE_REMOTE_SERVER_CFG 0

GSKIT_VERSION 

NETTYPE drsoctcp,1,150,NET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a multiprocessor machine, definitely consider turning on `MULTIPROCESSOR` by setting it to a non-zero value.

The ONCONFIG parameters of greatest interest to you for DSS are those related to Parallel Data Query, or PDQ. The block that commences with MAX_PDQPRIORITY. It is worth perusing the fine manual on these specifically, because the inter-relationship between them and some other parameters is too complex to go into here.

But in essence, `DS_MAX_QUERIES` is the maxumum number of parallel queries permitted at any time, and `DS_MAX_SCANS` determines the number of IO threads for scanning your tables. `DS_TOTAL_MEMORY` determines the amount of memory allocated for PDQ processing, and there is an algorithm in the manual that shows how these variables and the user's `PDQPRIORITY` setting combine.

You might also want to consider lifting the `RA_PAGES` and `RA_THRESHOLD` values - these determine how many pages are read into memory as 'blocks' before grabbing the next batch. If you're wanting to favour table-scans (which generally you do in DSS) then increasing these to something like 256 and 128 might improve performance.

My experience is with SMP and MPP unix boxes, rather than Windows, so I'm not sure how much you can wring out of your architecture, but this is where you want to start.

I would recommend identifying a good DSS query that runs for a decent length of time, and changing one parameter at a time to see the effect. `SET EXPLAIN ON` is your friend here, too.

One last thing - 11.7 supports table compression, and the tests I've seen show dramatic improvements in a DSS environment with large reads and irregular writes.

Comment: Basically, there's only one user (me) who will be doing DSS queries against a 200MB table, joining to a couple of fact tables. No inserts, updates or deletes will be done against any tables in this DSS app. Are there any other parameters that I should disable or lower their values which would increase the performance of my DSS queries?.. Should I disable transaction logging, etc.?

Comment: Well, if there are no updates/deletes, you shouldn't have to worry about transactions. Whether you want to muck about with things like check point interval, or turning off logging completely depends to a large extent on what else there is in this database, and how this data gets loaded. There is a very good PDF on the topic of DSS tuning amongst the manuals.