# Why does oninit automatically lower memory for non-parallel query memory?

Tags: informix

Informix 11.70.TC5DE (Windows Vista 32-bit):

I configured an instance for DSS queries with 512MB memory and 300MB disk space.
Why did oninit automatically change my non-parallel query's memory to only 94464kb, when I specified that only one user would be submitting DSS queries?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of the DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM (non-parallel query memory) is limited to 25% of the total PDQ (aka DS or Decision Support) memory.  So you would need to increase DS_TOTAL_MEMORY to get a larger value for DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM.  On the other hand, 90 MiB of non-PDQ memory is fairly generous; it probably isn't worth fretting over the exact size of the non-PDQ memory.

I'd be more worried about the size of the created resident pool (6580 KiB according to the screenshot).  Generally speaking, use the available memory for the buffer pool.  If, as I suspect, your database is less than about 100 MiB total, then the whole thing will be in memory anyway.  With 512 MiB on the machine, I'd aim to have Informix using about 128 MiB for all of its shared memory, leaving the rest for the O/S and (other) programs to use.  And that 128 MiB will have most of a 100 MiB database in the shared memory by virtue of caching, so you won't see much disk traffic after the data is read — unless you go rewriting lots and lots of data, of course.

See the [Informix 11.70 Information Centre](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117) for more information about [DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0064.htm).

Comment: Understood!.. When installing TC5, I told it to create a custom DSS instance with 300MB of space, thus reason why I allocated 512MB of memory, thinking the whole instance could be in-memory. Besides increasing BUFFERPOOL, although my TC4 DSS disk allocation was 212MB, should I basically use the same onconfig params that were suggested to me in my previous SO [question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477914/which-of-the-ids-11-70-onconfig-parameters-can-be-changed-to-maximize-performanc)

Comment: CORRECTION: Resident pool, not BUFFERPOOL.